# Comparing the input with two table

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a LOGIN PAGE which has one table in my database which is members include ID, PASSWORD, USER_TYPE.
I want my login page that when users enter their ID and password go to the website based on who they are. (If they are students go to student's page) (If they are organizer go to organizer's page).

I can't get the result from coding below:

```
<?php

        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

        $user="admin";
        $pass="neehahs";
        $host="localhost";
        $db="login";

         $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
                  if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }


        $username=($_POST['username']);
        $password=md5($_POST['password']);

        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);




        $sql="SELECT * FROM members WHERE student_id='%$username%' AND student_pass='%$password%'";
        $sqldata=mysqli_query($con,$sql)
        or die ("error");

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata)){

        if($row["user_type"]=='student'){
    header('location: http://localhost/greenstudio/index.html');

        }

elseif
    ($row["user_type"]=='organizer'){
    header('location: http://localhost/greenstudio/index2.html');

    }else {
        echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";


    }
    }
    exit();     
        }

          ?>
```

Comment: Why do you don't have a single table with logins and a field that identify if the user is a organizer or student?

Comment: BTW, your search is very inefficient, try adding a WHERE clause in your query to get only the users who match.

Comment: @Drudge when i enter the id and pass of student it gives me my else condition which is your credentials are not valid

Comment: @Babblo can you tell me how to put both in one single table and compare them

Comment: You can use extra column role to maintain this

Comment: yes the best idea is the idea of @innovative Kundan  . Insert all the users in same table and just add the column "role" which will differentiate the user of which i.e. organizer or student.And use where clause in your query to check the user of which role.. :)

Comment: Your logic is VERY VERY inefficient... you should really get some more basics of MySQL and how to properly and efficiently write queries. Have the database do all the work that you can possibly make it do and then let PHP handle the rest. That will make your queries run faster and your application faster overall.

Comment: @Shane using `student_id='%$username%' AND student_pass='%$password%'` is VERY VERY BAD as then usernames and passwords do not have to be exact and then two users one with student and the other with astudent1 could both log in with username student. Do not use `%` when comparing usernames and passwords for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a table similar to:

```
Table: users
--------+----------+----------+----------
user_id | username | password | user_type
--------+----------+----------+----------
1       | admin    | neehahs  | organizer
2       | student1 | mypass   | student
```

And then you can write a query like:

```
SELECT
  user_type
FROM
  users
WHERE
  BINARY username='$username' AND
  BINARY password='$password'
```

Then your if:else if:else statement would just redirect on whether the return was student or organizer; and no returned rows would equal invalid log in.

**Note:**
use `BINARY` comparisons with log ins to ensure that usernames are entered case sensitive and you should use some kind of encryption on your password field md5 at the very least but stronger encryption is highly recommended

**Edit:** here is how I would write this logic:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $user="admin";
    $pass="neehahs";
    $host="localhost";
    $db="login";
    $con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $username=($_POST['username']);
    $password=md5($_POST['password']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
    $sql="SELECT user_type FROM members WHERE BINARY student_id='$username' AND BINARY student_pass='$password'";
    $sqldata=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ("error");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata);
    if(is_null($row) || mysqli_num_rows($sqldata)!=1){
        echo "Sorry, your credentials are not valid or matches more than 1 user, Please try again.";
    } else if(isset($row["user_type"])){
        if($row["user_type"]=='student'){
            header('location: http://localhost/greenstudio/index.html');
        } else if($row["user_type"]=='organizer'){
            header('location: http://localhost/greenstudio/index2.html');
        } else {
            echo "User type was returned as not student nor organizer.";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, user_type was not returned in the dataset retrieved from the database.";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: take  look at my code now ,, when i submit my login disappear without any error

Comment: @Shane please see my edited answer for a better logic and more error handling of different results. Also make sure that you also md5 the passwords in the actual database and are not comparing md5 values against clear text passwords

Comment: @Shane remember to vote up ^ any comments, answers, or questions that you find good or helpful.

Comment: sure, iwill  ,, im new to this community ,, not enough reputation to vote ,, sorry ,, once i had enough i will vote your answer 100